# Android transition with FAB button

Tags: android, transition

According to these guidelines I want to show / hide my FAB button when the activity start and finish.
https://material.io/guidelines/motion/material-motion.html#material-motion-what-makes-a-good-transition
I'm using Shared Element Activity Transition to display my detail activity like so:
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Shared-Element-Activity-Transition

CardAdapter.java

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CardViewHolder holder, int position) {
    [...]
    holder.getBinding().setVariable(BR.handler, mHandler);
    holder.getBinding().executePendingBindings();
}
```

CardHandler.java

```
public class CardHandler {
    private Activity mActivity;

    CardHandler(Activity activity) {
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    public void onCardClick(View view, Module module) {
        final Context context = view.getContext();
        final Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(DetailActivity.MODULE, module);

        View image = view.findViewById(R.id.card_image);
        View description = view.findViewById(R.id.card_description);

        Pair<View, String> p1 = Pair.create(image, "image");
        Pair<View, String> p2 = Pair.create(description, "description");

        ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat
                .makeSceneTransitionAnimation(mActivity, p1, p2);

        context.startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
    }
}
```

DetailActivity.java

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ViewDataBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_detail);

    // Enable back button
    setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
    if (null != getSupportActionBar()) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    // Retrieve module from extra
    final Module module = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(MODULE);

    // Bind module data
    binding.setVariable(BR.module, module);
    mFabAction = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_action);

    addTransitionEnterListener();
}

private boolean addTransitionEnterListener() {
    final Transition transition = getWindow().getSharedElementEnterTransition();
    if (transition == null) return false;
    transition.addListener(new Transition.TransitionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTransitionEnd(Transition transition) {
            mFabAction.show();
            transition.removeListener(this);
            addTransitionReturnListener();
        }
    });
    return true;
}

private boolean addTransitionReturnListener() {
    final Transition transition = getWindow().getSharedElementReturnTransition();

    if (transition == null) return false;
    transition.addListener(new Transition.TransitionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTransitionStart(Transition transition) {
            mFabAction.hide();
            transition.removeListener(this);
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

The hide method doesn't work properly, my fab button get overlapped by my layout during the transition.

https://youtu.be/p0Wam_bqn7I

Comment: It can be available with mActivity object ?

Comment: I tried to do  
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.fab_action);  
fab.show();
Before  context.startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());  
It returns null pointer

Comment: you can hide from where you can start your new activity.

Comment: The fab button is only present in my DetailActivity, my CardAdapter only contains a RecyclerView with a list of CardView.

Comment: you can create methods for hide and show FAB in activity, and pass activity object with you. you can hide and show FAB as you want with activity object.

Comment: FloatingButtonAction already contain the methods show/hide, the problem is to know where I should can them :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130953/discussion-between-naitik-and-melkir).